# What is the Unix command to display all lines of a file with two certain strings

Tags: regex, file, shell, unix, command

Basically, I have a file that I want to search and display only the lines that have the strings 'abc' and 'vhg'.  What is the Unix command for this?

Comment: Is it that the line must contain both 'abc' AND 'vhg', or the line must contain either 'abc' OR 'vhg' (or both)?  And if it must be both, is it in the order 'abc' then 'vhg', or does the reverse order also count?  Also, are you using GNU `grep` or are you on some other system?  Some of the answers are applicable to GNU `grep` and not other variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` for it:

```
grep abc file.txt | grep vhg
```

OR

you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/abc/ && /vhg/' file.txt
```

One more way with grep:

```
grep .*abc.*vhg file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grep` command.

```
grep 'word1\|word2\|word3' /path/to/file
```

Example:

```
grep 'abc\|vhg' filename
```

Comment: `|` means `OR`. Its not `AND`

Answer (score 0):

Since a `sed` solution has not yet been given:

```
sed -n '/abc/{ /vhg/p; }'
```